# Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on some data on party polarization ([something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3M1F.png)) and used `geom_dumbbell` from `ggalt` and `ggplot2`. I keep getting the same `aes` error and other solutions in the forum did not address this as effectively. This is my sample data.

```
    df <- data_frame(policy=c("Not enough restrictions on gun ownership", "Climate change is an immediate threat", "Abortion should be illegal"),
             Democrats=c(0.54, 0.82, 0.30),
             Republicans=c(0.23, 0.38, 0.40),
             diff=sprintf("+%d", as.integer((Democrats-Republicans)*100)))
```

I wanted to keep order of the plot, so converted policy to `factor` and wanted % to be shown only on the first line.

```
    df <- arrange(df, desc(diff))
    df$policy <- factor(df$policy, levels=rev(df$policy))

    percent_first <- function(x) {
    x <- sprintf("%d%%", round(x*100))
    x[2:length(x)] <- sub("%$", "", x[2:length(x)])
    x
    }
```

Then I used ggplot that rendered something close to what I wanted.

```
   gg2 <- ggplot()
   gg2 <- gg + geom_segment(data = df, aes(y=country, yend=country, x=0, xend=1), color = "#b2b2b2", size = 0.15)

  # making the dumbbell
  gg2 <- gg + geom_dumbbell(data=df, aes(y=country, x=Democrats, xend=Republicans),
                     size=1.5, color = "#B2B2B2", point.size.l=3, point.size.r=3,
                     point.color.l = "#9FB059", point.color.r = "#EDAE52")
```

I then wanted the dumbbell to read `Democrat` and `Republican` on top to label the two points ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3M1F.png)). This is where I get the error.

```
    gg2 <- gg + geom_text(data=filter(df, country=="Government will not control gun violence"),
                  aes(x=Democrats, y=country, label="Democrats"),
                  color="#9fb059", size=3, vjust=-2, fontface="bold", family="Calibri")
    gg2 <- gg + geom_text(data=filter(df, country=="Government will not control gun violence"),
                 aes(x=Republicans, y=country, label="Republicans"),
                 color="#edae52", size=3, vjust=-2, fontface="bold", family="Calibri")
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: where does `country` come from?

Comment: Are you trying to reference `gg` or `gg2`?!

Comment: `aes` call accepts variables defined in `data`, `label="Republicans"` is not a variable but a constant string hence the error

Comment: @bouncyball sorry, my bad. I may have posted an older version of the code. I changed all gg2 to gg, so it's consistent. That's not where the problem is.

Comment: @Nate I may have accidentally posted an older version of the code with inconsistent variable names. I have changed them -- it should read "policy" wherever it says "country" in this code.

Comment: @missuse I thought I had named the data columns `Democrats` and `Republicans` Isn't `label` supposed to just add text to it? Are there suggestions on how the code should be written differently?

Comment: @sdiya provide some data and I will try to provide a solution. Generally in the `aes` call you provide variables from `data`, if one wants to give a constant to the plot he will do it outside the `aes` call: like `... aes(x=Republicans, y=country), label="Republicans"...` - I do not guarantee it will make sense in this plot since I do not have the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to build your own "dumbbells" with `geom_segment()` and `geom_point()`. Working with your `df` and changing the variable refences "country" to "policy":

```
library(tidyverse)

# gather data into long form to make ggplot happy
df2 <- gather(df,"party", "value", Democrats:Republicans)

ggplot(data = df2, aes(y = policy, x = value, color = party)) +
    # our dumbell
    geom_path(aes(group = policy), color = "#b2b2b2", size = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 7, show.legend = FALSE) +
    # the text labels
    geom_text(aes(label = party), vjust = -1.5) + # use vjust to shift text up to no overlap
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Democrats" = "blue", "Republicans" = "red")) + # named vector to map colors to values in df2
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1), labels = scales::percent) # use library(scales) nice math instead of pasting
```

Produces this plot:

[image]
Which has some overlapping labels. I think you could avoid that if you use just the first letter of party like this:

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(y = policy, x = value, color = party)) +
    geom_path(aes(group = policy), color = "#b2b2b2", size = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 7, show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_text(aes(label = gsub("^(\\D).*", "\\1", party)),  vjust = -1.5) + # just the first letter instead
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Democrats" = "blue", "Republicans" = "red"),
                       guide = "none") +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1), labels = scales::percent)
```

Only label the top issue with names:

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(y = policy, x = value, color = party)) +
    geom_path(aes(group = policy), color = "#b2b2b2", size = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 7, show.legend = FALSE) +
    geom_text(data = filter(df2, policy == "Not enough restrictions on gun ownership"),
                     aes(label = party), vjust = -1.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Democrats" = "blue", "Republicans" = "red")) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1), labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: This works, thanks. My original thinking was just having labels on the top for the first row and let color codes do the rest.

Comment: Sure if you want to label just the first row, you have a couple of options, I'm going to add one to the answer